# What to call the new spanner / wrench menu in Chrome 22?

Tags: google-chrome

My version of Chrome has just upgraded to version 22 and the *spanner* (or *wrench*) menu button has changed to three horizontal lines!?

[image]

This is going to be very confusing for all those reading documentation that refers to a "spanner menu".

So, what do I now call the "spanner" menu that is no longer a "spanner"?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6307310#6307310

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called the [Chrome menu](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95414) (according to Google). Picture from the site:

> Click the Chrome menu [image] on the browser toolbar

Comment: text is indexed by search engines, images are not ;) (also the jpeg artifacts were kinda bugging me...)

Answer (score 2):

The three bars are also known as `Hamburger Navigation` - presumably since they (very) loosely resemble a hamburger!

See https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/32877/what-is-this-side-menu-called-that-can-be-found-in-many-multi-touch-apps-and-wh

Comment: I believe "*hamburger navigation*" refers to the stacking panels as presented in the question you've linked, not the icon itself.

Comment: It might be so originally, but I'm certainly not the only one to interpret the icon that way: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=3+lines+hamburger (ignoring any random baby ultrasound results!)